# React Build Failing - how to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, debugging

I have a React Frontend Project that works correctly with `npm start` - the frontend works as expected when I run it this way.

However, when I `npm run build` and then serve the file with express, the frontend fails. The frontend doesn't load in my browser and I see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: l[e] is undefined` on Firefox and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` on Chrome.

The stack trace associated with those errors isn't very helpful as it just directs to chunk.js. I need to somehow figure out what's causing this issue. My boss suggested someone else working on the project likely made a coding error and we'll have to clean up everything to debug (this setup was working a week ago). Is there anything I can do to debug this short of going through every line of code?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Did you find a fix for the error? I have the same problem

Comment: Just searched through slack, I think removing these imports was the fix, but I can't recall for certain. 

```import { timeDay } from 'd3';  
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';```